# Navigation component arguments default value

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-architecture

In navigation component, While sending arguments from first fragment to second fragment, default values are not getting which set from navigation graph.

Here is my code:

**navigation_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.navigationcomponent.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim" />

        <argument
            android:name="clickFrom"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="From First Fragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="clickFragmentPosition"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="1" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.navigationcomponent.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />


</navigation>
```

**FirstFragment:**

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putBoolean("IsFirstFragment", true)
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)

        btnNext.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment, bundle)
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondFragment:**

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val isFromFirstFragment = arguments?.getBoolean("IsFirstFragment", false)
        Log.d(TAG, "$isFromFirstFragment")
        Log.d(TAG, "${FirstFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).clickFrom} ${FirstFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).clickFragmentPosition}")

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)
        btnBack.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigateUp()
        }

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
            Log.d("TAG", "${destination.label}");
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG: String = "SecondFragment"
    }
}
```

Here while fetching default values in second fragment I am getting Null Pointer Exception

```
Log.d(TAG, "${FirstFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).clickFrom} ${FirstFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).clickFragmentPosition}")
```

My Question is, How can I get values of arguments set using `navigation_graph.xml`? Navigation Graph have auto-generated getter when you re-build the project. Is there any architecture to bind auto generated setters using default value?

Comment: You can't grab `FirstFragment`'s arguments from `SecondFragment`. `FirstFragmentArgs` is only available to be retrieved in `FirstFragment`. What is your intended functionality with this code? I can provide you with some suggestions for your implementation if you need.

Comment: I want to pass arguments from one fragment to second fragment as I did as bundle in FirstFragment. Instead of bundles  I want to send arguments using navigation_graph as I have mentioned in code. As I did in SecondFragment I want to retrieve arguments which are send using navigation graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send arguments from `FirstFragment` to `SecondFragment`, then you should replace your **navigation_graph.xml** with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.navigationcomponent.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.navigationcomponent.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">

        <argument
            android:name="clickFrom"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="From First Fragment" />

        <argument
            android:name="clickFragmentPosition"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="1" />

        <argument
            android:name="isFirstFragment"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />

    </fragment>


</navigation>
```

Then, you can pass arguments from your **FirstFragment** like this:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)

        btnNext.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(
                FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment( // this is an auto-generated class & method
                    // specify your arguments here: For example:
                    isFirstFragment = true,
                    clickFrom = "your argument here",
                    clickFragmentPosition = 1
                    // for default values, you can leave this blank
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Then to retrieve arguments in **SecondFragment**

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

    private val arguments: SecondFragmentArgs by navArgs() // add this line to retrieve arguments from navigation

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val isFromFirstFragment = arguments.isFirstFragment
        Log.d(TAG, "$isFromFirstFragment")
        Log.d(TAG, "${arguments.clickFrom} ${arguments.clickFragmentPosition}")

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)
        btnBack.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigateUp()
        }

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
            Log.d("TAG", "${destination.label}");
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG: String = "SecondFragment"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. While getting values I am not directly getting using arguments.clickFrom

I need to do like this:
val clickFromFragment = SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).clickFrom

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is trying to use navigation arguments in Java this is how you retrieve arguments in SecondFragment

```
boolean isFirstFragment = SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getIsFirstFragment();
```