# How to use Float.MAX_VALUE as default value for navigation argument?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin i can use constant Float.MAX_VALUE to get maximum float value. I want to use it in my navigation graph as default value for argument:

```
<argument
            android:name="floatValue"
            android:defaultValue="*want to use MAX_VALUE here*"
            app:argType="float" />
```

can we do it somehow?

Comment: did u gone through this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59351475/9181430

Comment: @RohitKumar it's just a regular case. In my case i want to use constant as default value so i need to create xml resource with float value or something like that

Comment: why you hesitate to add direct const value instead of Float.MAX_VALUE, its value is constant so put it

Comment: @RohitKumar i'm using deeplink for navigating i'm sorry that i didn't point that in my description. So i'm getting arguments from URI

Comment: if u want to use variable in xml then add data binding

Comment: or set default value using code at run time